# Checking Duplicate Records in Table Where Id is Identity

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, identity, record

In my table, ID is primary key field and identity column.
I want to check duplicate records.
(Certainly duplicate records do not have same ID)

And do not have date fields same.

How do I check this.

Extra Detail: I have 10 columns with 1 ID, 2 Date, and other 3 string, 3 Int, 1 bit.

Thansk in Advance.

Comment: EDIT: duplicate will have "other 3 string, 3 Int, 1 bit.
" columns same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` to group similar records to count them, and then add a `HAVING` clause to filter out only those that occur more than once:

```
select StringCol1, StringCol2, StringCol3, IntCol1, IntCol2, IntCol3, BitCol1, count(*) as Count
from MyTable
group by StringCol1, StringCol2, StringCol3, IntCol1, IntCol2, IntCol3, BitCol1
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use GROUP BY to group similar records and HAVING to specify condition on them.

```
select count(string1), count(string2),count(string3),count(int1), count(int2),count(int3),count(bit1)
from table1
group by string1, string2, string3, int1, int2, int3, bit1
having count(string1) > 1 and count(string2) > 1 and count(string3) > 1 and count(int1) > 1 and count(int2) > 1 and count(int3) > 1 and count(bit1) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A generalized approach would be as follows. hope this helps you.

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, ..., COLn, COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE1 
GROUP BY COL1,COL2, .., COLn 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```